# Waiting Decision After Phone Interview (PhD)... Should I Email them?

Tags: graduate-admissions, interview

I just recently did two phone interviews (one with the professor on the admission committee and the other with prospective PI) and was told that if I was offered admission, they would invite me for an on-site interview for sometime next week.

After the phone interview, I emailed the program coordinator at the department regarding when the admission decision will be made. She told me she would know by this morning (morning of the day I have written this post), yet I am still waiting to hear back from them.

Would it be okay to email them back to ask whether I was offered admission or not? Or should I just wait?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd generally suggest you wait at least 24-48 hours after the quoted time unless your need is particularly urgent for some reason, as it's naturally to be a little delayed in...well, any decision making scenario. "later that day" seems a little jumpy.

Comment: @BrianDHall I agree. Thank you for your input. I have exams lined up on the week of the on-site interview and thought I might ask. Since they really didn't specify when they would notify me, I guess I should just wait.